# how to pause and play sound

Tags: c, audio

Hey all I want to play a sound. I issue a c command and it plays the sound, then the user presses a key, let's say "h" and then the sound stops for 5 seconds, and returns after 5 seconds. What c command can i use to do this? I thought mci send string might work, but I'm not sure.
Play Sound was my go to but it doesn't have this functionality.

any code suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows

1. Use the `waveOutPause()` to pause the audio.
2. Use `Sleep(5000);`
3. Use the `waveOutRestart()` to start the audio from where it paused.

See also: [waveOutPause MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910079.aspx)